# WebStorage with RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am trying to access WebStorage when running my tests, I am running tests locally using ChromeDriver and remotely in the pipeline using RemoteWebDriver.

I am unable to access WebStorage when using RemoteWebDriver

```
WebStorage webStorage = (RemoteWebStorage) new Augmenter().augment(driver);
```

I am getting:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.remote.html5.RemoteWebStorage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to use below hack to access the local storage in RemoteWebDriver . Tested it on chrome browser using RemoteWebdriver selenium-java - 4.0.0-alpha-2 , Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 and ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 . Working fine for me.

Import below classes

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.html5.RemoteWebStorage;
 import org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocalStorage;
```

Use below code to access the local storage

```
 RemoteExecuteMethod executeMethod = new RemoteExecuteMethod((RemoteWebDriver) driver);
 RemoteWebStorage webStorage = new RemoteWebStorage(executeMethod);
 LocalStorage storage = webStorage.getLocalStorage();
 storage.setItem("test", "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot one import `import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;`